# Stopping a running bash script from another script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting, kill-process

I have a script called **first.sh** and this script calls another script using "**./second.sh**". In **second.sh** there are commands to play songs. For example, the content of **second.sh** could be:

```
play song1.mp3
play song2.mp3
...
```

I want to stop the script **second.sh** at certain times during the day, the problem is that using **killall** (and similar commands) do not help because the name of the script "**second.sh**" does not appear among the list of commands when I use "**ps aux**", I only see "**play song1.mp3**" and then "**play song2.mp3**" once song2 starts playing.

What can I do to stop **second.sh** using a command in the terminal? Or at least tie all the commands in it to a single process so I can kill that particular process?

Any help is appreciated, I've tried many ideas I found online but nothing seems to work.

Comment: you should be able to see both first.sh and second.sh with ps aux when second.sh is running.  double check the filename thats being executed from first.sh script to make sure you're searching for the right thing

Comment: What about if, instead of killing the "play" command, along with the script the calls the "play" command, you were simply to adjust the audio output level during those time of day when you want silence?

Comment: I did check, I ran "ps aux | grep second.sh" and nothing came up. All I see are the individual commands as they are being executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you said :

> at certain times during the day,

I would recommend `crontab`.

Use `crontab -e` and append the below line

```
0 12 * * * kill -9 `ps aux | awk '/play/{print $2}'`
```

This kills the parent shell that invoked `play`

The syntax for the crontab file is

```
m h  dom mon dow   command
```

**where:**

m - minute
h - hours
dom - day of month
mon - month
dow - day of week 
command - the command that you wish to execute.

**Edit**

Or you could do something like this :

```
0 12 * * * killall -sSIGSTOP play
0 16 * * * killall -sSIGCONT play
```

which will pause all the `play` processes from 12 hours till 16 hours.

**Requirement**

You need to have the cron daemon up and running on your system.

Comment: There are 2 problems with this:
1) second.sh does not appear in the list of running processes, so using killall will not work.
2) pausing and stopping play will only cause the second "play" command in "second.sh" to run

Comment: I will give it a try now!

Comment: It worked!! Thank you!! The playing paused at the specified time (and the script didn't move to the next play command) and then resumed at the specified time. This is what I needed! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can save the pgid of the process explicitly, and then use the signals SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to start and stop the process group.

first.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

nohup ./second.sh > /dev/null 2>&1 &
echo $$ > /tmp/play.pid ### save process group id
```

second.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

play ...
play ...
```

third.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in
    (start)
        kill -CONT -$(cat /tmp/play.pid)
        ;;

    (stop)
        kill -STOP -$(cat /tmp/play.pid)
        ;;
esac
```

Now you can launch and control the play as follows:

```
./first.sh

./third.sh stop
./third.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to stop second.sh and it will kill all its child processes automatically.

```
killall second.sh
```